# XAMPP Server Error (Error 500)

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, xampp

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 500
>   localhost
>   Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30

I opened the log error and found out that the issue is about the header() i have in my user.inc.php:

```
function getLogin($conn){
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $uid=$_POST['uid'];
    $pwd=$_POST['pwd'];

    $sql= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid='$uid' AND pwd ='$pwd'";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                header("Location : index.php?loginsuccess");
                exit();
        }
    }
    else{



    }
}
}
```

The error log :

> [Tue Jul 25 10:26:58.464402 2017] [http:error] [pid 2380:tid 1656] [client ::1:49602] AH02429: Response header name 'Location ' contains invalid characters, aborting request, referer: http://localhost/tgss/index.php

Please, help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this

```
header("Location : index.php?loginsuccess");
```

to this

```
header("Location: index.php?loginsuccess");
```

The error came from the space between `Location` and the colon ( `:` ).

I tested your `header("Location : index.php?loginsuccess");` that have space between the colon ( `:` ), and it also return an `Error 500`

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location : index.php?loginsuccess");
```

Use below one

```
header("Location: index.php?loginsuccess");
```

It gives error only space between **Location** and `:` so remove the space like this **Location**:

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
header("Location : path");
```

To

```
header("Location: path");
```

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location: path");` 
path like login.php
'L' of Location should be capital
no gap b/w 'Location' and ':'